# Docker Compose Containers with specific hostpath on nginx

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, reverse-proxy

I have two docker containers running with docker-compose and nginx.
I want to run each one on it specific hostpath. (Running them on it own port also will work for me)

```
http://host/container1
http://host/container2
or 
http://host:80
http://host:81
```

I got my nginx template from: https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/blob/master/nginx.tmpl

I'm able to run them separately, So they run fine as single containers with nginx.
I have tried modifying the `location / { proxy_pass ..  }` to send to different port (localhost:80, localhost:81).

Added to L237 https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/blob/master/nginx.tmpl

```
location /container1 {
    proxy_pass {{ trim $proto }}://{{ trim $host }};
}

location /container2 {
    proxy_pass {{ trim $proto }}://{{ trim $host }}:81;
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx-container:
    image: nginx
    container_name: nginx-container
    ports:
    # "server_host_port:nginx_container_port"
      - "80:80"
      - "81:81"
    volumes:
      - /etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./docker-gen/proxy.conf:/etc/nginx/proxy.conf
  docker-gen:
    image: jwilder/docker-gen
    command: -notify-sighup nginx-container -watch /etc/docker-gen/templates/nginx.tmpl /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    volumes_from:
      - nginx-container
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - ./docker-gen/nginx.tmpl:/etc/docker-gen/templates/nginx.tmpl
  container-one:
    build: ./container-one
    image: docker.repository.testing.com/container-one
# Exposing 8080 for dockergen
    expose:
      - 8080
    environment:
      - spring.profiles.active=docker,testing
      - nginx.host=nginx-container
      - nginx.port=80
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=host
    links:
      - nginx-container
    depends_on:
      - nginx-container
  container-two:
    build: ./container-two
    image: docker.repository.testing.com/container-two
# Exposing 8080 for dockergen
    expose:
      - 8080
    environment:
      - spring.profiles.active=docker,testing
      - nginx.host=nginx-container
      - nginx.port=81
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=host
    links:
      - nginx-container
      - container-one
    depends_on:
      - nginx-container
      - container-one
```

As I understand it:
I have my container-one and container-two running like this:

```
container-one -> nginx-container:80
container-two -> nginx-container:81
```

Both using the virtual_host "host"

So I should be able to change "location" in the nginx.tmpl file to point to the host:port on the containers

However this doesn't work...
Sometimes I get the nginx welcome page sometimes I got a 503 or 404

I'm not sure what I'm missing or doing wrong.
Is this the right way to configure this?

References:
https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy
https://gist.github.com/soheilhy/8b94347ff8336d971ad0
https://github.com/nbellocam/sample-site-docker/blob/master/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
http://jasonwilder.com/blog/2014/03/25/automated-nginx-reverse-proxy-for-docker/

Comment: If you want 2 distinct containers, you will need different ports or a third one acting as reverse proxy.

Comment: Each container runs on it port and the nginx is the reverse proxy :) Unless I have something wrong...

Comment: I have a setup like that on my server, i star this question, if you don't get help, i'll send you my compose file tomorow morning.

Comment: I'll really appreciate that :)

Comment: does it work without your changes to nginx.tmpl ?

Comment: yes, they run fine as single containers without modifying the location on nginx.tmpl

Comment: maybe you could provide the genreated config file, because it is hard to tell, without it...

Comment: why wouldn't you just use VIRTUAL_PORT?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using two `VIRTUAL_HOST`, one for each container.

```
host.container1.com
host.container2.com
```

This worked, although I had to add a new host to match the virtual host.